# How to delete all content in file in vscode vim?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

In normal .vimrc I have following mapping:

```
:nnoremap <leader>s G$vggx
```

To delete everything from bottom to up. I would like to something similar in VS Code vim plugin (in `settings.json`):

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindings": [
 {
  "before" : ["leader", "s"],
  "after" : ["G$vggx"]
 }
],
```

Of course does nothing, but having type it manually, then it works. So how to make the vs extension accept these key sequence?

Comment: try to use the naive nvim plugin, there you can use your init.vim in vscode. See: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=asvetliakov.vscode-neovim

Comment: @Chelz, so that plugin is native for vscode? And from the link, I can use init.vim for vimscript?

Comment: Install the plugin through vscode. Init.vim ist neovims equivalent to vim's vimrc

Comment: @Chelz I did install, but the do not know, how to use `init.vim` and where to find it. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62727830/how-to-activate-keybindings-from-neovim-in-vscode

Comment: If you already have a vimrc try `:h nvim-from-vim` in nvim. If you don't, try `:h init.vim`

Comment: not directly relevant for your question. But `ggdG` would be more efficient than `G$vggx`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two solutions that come to mind.

## Using the built-in [vim-textobj-entire](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#vim-textobj-entire)

The text object `ae` represents the entire content of a buffer in Vim for VSCode. You can use this text object in combination with the `d` command.

`dae`

## Adding your own mapping

Add the following to your `settings.json` file in VSCode.

```
    "vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {
        "before": ["<leader>", "s"],
        "after": ["g", "g", "d", "G"]
        }
     ]
```

Then you can type `<leader>-s` to delete the contents of your current editor.

Please note that it is not necessary to visual select what you want to delete; therefore I used `ggdG`.