# How to activate keybindings from neovim in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, neovim

According to their readme: [https://github.com/asvetliakov/vscode-neovim#custom-keybindings](https://github.com/asvetliakov/vscode-neovim), I have put the following in `~/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json`:

```
[
    {
        "command": "vscode-neovim.compositeEscape2",
        "key": "k",
        "when": "neovim.mode == insert",
        "args": "k"
    }
]
```

However, after saving and restarting the vs, the escape is still not triggered when `jk` is pressed. Why is it?

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you have neovim installed then add the following to your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
    "command": "vscode-neovim.compositeEscape1",
    "key": "j",
    "when": "neovim.mode == insert",
    "args": "j"
},
{
    "command": "vscode-neovim.compositeEscape2",
    "key": "k",
    "when": "neovim.mode == insert",
    "args": "k"
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I used to use neovim, but because it is not as easy to add new keybindings/command,  it is sufficient for me to have classic vim as plugin, no need for neovim (I see no added value to already so powerful vim), but thanks anyway